# How to upload the pdf/doc file in laravel through validation

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a website where the user will be able to upload the pdf and doc file. Also, I want to save the file in the storage folder so I made the symlink so it would replicate the folder in the Public folder. SO I have a folder called Public/storage/Paper in public. This is my form where the user will be able to upload the paper.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="paper" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title of Paper</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title"  placeholder="Title of Paper" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Paper">Upload Paper</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="paper" required="required" >
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On my controller, I wrote this code, this works perfectly fine like saving the data in the database when I don't need to upload the file. But when I need to upload the paper the validation doesn't pass.

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Submission;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
 class PapersController extends Controller
{


public function  store(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'paper'=>'required'

    ]);


    $title= $request->input('title');
    Validator::make($request->all(),['file'=>"required|string|paper|mimes:pdf,docx"])->validate();
    $extension= $request->file("file")->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $stringPaperFormat=str_replace(" ", "", $request->input('title'));

    $fileName= $stringPaperFormat.".".$extension;
   $FileEnconded=  File::get($request->paper);
    Storage::disk('local')->put('public/Paper'.$fileName, $FileEnconded);
    $newsubmission= array("title"=>$title, "first_name"=>$first_name, "last_name"=>$last_name,"isReviewed"=>$isReviewed, "paper"=>$fileName);
    $created= DB::table('submissions')->insert($newsubmission);
    if($created){
        return "Sucessful";
    }else{
        return "Not Sucessful";
    }


}
```

}

I am not being able to detect the problem. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `doc` and `docs` are `zip` files so you need to add `zip` instead of `doc` or `docx` in your validation rule

Also your field name is `paper` and you are using `file` while creating validation. Change `file` to `paper`. And your are using `paper` rule in your file upload validations that is not an inbuilt validation rule so remove that too.

> **Change**

```
 Validator::make($request->all(),['file'=>"required|string|paper|mimes:pdf,docx"])->validate();
```

> **to**

```
 Validator::make($request->all(),['paper'=>"required|string|mimes:pdf,zip"])->validate();
```

References:
[Laracast ->  How to make validation rules to upload pdf, doc and docx files in laravel 5.4](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/how-to-make-validation-rules-to-upload-pdf-doc-and-docx-files-in-laravel-54)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Comment: Thank you @Sehdev, I did make the changes but it still is not working. Can you please help me out.

Comment: try all these mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip. Also it seems your field name is paper & you are using `file` while creating validation

Comment: Also it seems your field name is `paper` & you are using `file` while creating validation. Change `file` to `paper`

Comment: Yeah, when I change the  file to paper like this, 

Validator::make($request->all(),['paper'=>"required|string|paper|mimes:pdf,zip"])->validate();

It throws an error
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validatePaper does not exist.

Comment: You have defined  `paper` rule in your validation rules `required|string|paper`. Remove `paper` from this. Try this  Validator::make($request->all(),['paper'=>"required|string|mimes:pdf,zip"])->validate();